# Docker with NGINX Reverse Proxy for a Flask app

Tags: python, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm currently learning how to host websites and manage servers and especially how to host multisites inside a VPS. So I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy with jwilde/nginx-proxy.
But what I'm trying to understand is :

- Do the Reverse-Proxy will also be the web server for every app ? Or whenever I want to add an app via a container I have to launch an other web server (See Annexe 1)

> Annexe 1 [image: Annexe 1]

My current setup is :
[image]

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having a single container for your nginx reverse proxy, and only include nginx (or whatever other listener) where your other containers need one. You may have an opportunity to proxy_pass traffic directly to your Flask application without another nginx server.

However, your current setup and Annexe1 could be correct: you have the flexibility to use any host:port accepting traffic in your containers. It could even be another reverse proxy~ As long as your proxy_pass your traffic from your Reverse Proxy nginx to an appropriate listener.